# Delegate not responds to selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

Basically, I am now intend to use delegate to pass values between view controllers.

The flow of the view controllers is A -> B -> C using push segue.

When the user does some action in the "C" view controller, how to pass the value BACK to the first view controller, which is "A"?

In my code, "self.delegate" is always nil and the delegate method is never triggered.

Below is the code of the First VC and Third VC:

First VC .m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<PassValueProtocal>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    ThirdViewController *thirdVC;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void) passValueBack:(NSString *)value
{
    NSLog(@"HAHAH");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)segueToSecondVC:(UIButton *)sender
{
    thirdVC = [ThirdViewController sharedManager];

    thirdVC.delegate = self;
}

@end
```

Third VC .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol PassValueProtocal <NSObject>
- (void) passValueBack: (NSString *) value;
@end

@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<PassValueProtocal>delegate;
+ (id) sharedManager;

@end
```

Third VC .m:

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@interface ThirdViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;

@end

@implementation ThirdViewController

+ (id) sharedManager
{
    NSLog(@"myDelegate sharedManager");
    static ThirdViewController *sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{ sharedManager = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return sharedManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)passValueAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.delegate);
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(passValueBack:)])
    {
        [self.delegate passValueBack:self.myTextField.text];
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: where is the code of SecondVC where you push the ThirdVC. At that point, you need to pass forward delegate from Second to Third. That way ThirdVC will have delegate.

Comment: @iosDev82 Do you mean the delegate can only communicate with two view controllers which has segue relationship with each other?

Comment: No offense but your question is really ill put. At first you are talking about 3 VC, but your code has 2 view controllers.

Comment: @iosDev82 Sorry. I just leave the second VC blank, because I thought it's the communication between the firstVC and the thirdVC. What do I need to write for the secondVC? Does it act as something like a bridge? Sorry I am new learner to delegate...

Comment: If you create a UIViewController from storyboard, it won't call sharedManager. it will alloc a new object of ThirdViewController. so even if you set delegate to the ThirdViewController, but it is not the one that alloc by system

Comment: @iosDev82 The project I am doing has several VCs, when the user does some action on one of the VCs, it will trigger the change of the value of the first VC. Do you suggest me using delegate in this situation?

Comment: @jinhualiao So how can I set delegate to the thirdVC? I just try using [[alloc]init]; but same result...

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
- (IBAction)segueToSecondVC:(UIButton *)sender
{
    thirdVC = [ThirdViewController sharedManager];

    thirdVC.delegate = self;
}
```

Should not be here. You should implement function `prepareForSegue` and move this code there. Something like

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
ThirdViewController *thirdVC = (ThirdViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
thirdVC.delegate = self;

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I know how to use delegate between two view controllers, just using the method you provide. But this one seems to be segue from the firstVC directly to the thirdVC? Because the firstVC's destinationVC should be secondVC instead of thirdVC. Hence, is there anyway to pass value from the thirdVC back to the firstVC, but the segue goes through firstVC -> secondVC -> thirdVC?

Comment: Besides, is it possible to pass value from thirdVC back to firstVC directly?

Comment: @MikeZhu In your code that you shared, you've a button that does some sort of segue from FirstVC to ThirdVC. In either case, you should set delegate in `prepareForSegue` and do the same thing in `prepareForSegue` of SecondVC. This time you should pass SecondVC's delegate (which is fristVC) to ThirdVC delegate. Once you have delegate in ThirdVC, you can pass messaged directly to it.